# Chrome Extension and console.groupCollapsed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I intercept `console.groupCollapsed` from an active tab in my chrome extension?

I could intercept all logs except the ones inside a `groupCollapsed`

`chrome.debugger.onEvent` cant intercept  `groupCollapsed`, is there an alternative solution?

tried using chrome.debugger.onEvent but could only intercept log,error and warn

Comment: Assuming you use `Console.messageAdded` event, it's probably a bug in Chrome.